# IBOutlet is nil in drawRect method

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, null, iboutlet

I have a UIView subclass with a xib called `RoundedImageView`, which only implements the drawRect method. The xib contains an `AsyncImageView` (which is a subclass of `UIImageView`) with an outlet. This `RoundedImageView` is part of a custom table view cell. In the `awakeFromNib` method of this cell, the `RoundedImageView` is not nil, but it's `AsyncImageView` outlet is nil. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: have you connected the outlet to the object in the xib file?+

Comment: Yes, I have, in both xibs.

Comment: Then you didnt load the view from the NIB - show the loading code.

Comment: So, your asyncImageView is a subView to roundedImageView and also connected as outlet to rounedImageView?

Comment: That's the thing - I don't have any loading code. I just have drawRect in the view implementation and that's it. But drawRect gets called so I thought that the NIB did load.

Comment: Do you have IBOutlet variable asyncImageView declared in RoundedImageView.h and AsyncImageView is connected to IBOutlet in nib?

Comment: Yes, for both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with OP in chat, the issue turned out to be that the table cell / `RoundedImageView` was in one nib, and `RoundedImageView` with `AsycImageView` was in another. The solution was remove `RoundedImageView` from the cell, and load its nib in the cell's `awakeFromNib` method:

```
@implementation InviteFriendsImageVIew

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UINib *imageViewNib = [UINib nibWithName:@"RoundedImageView" bundle:nil];
    RoundedImageView *imageView = [imageViewNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil][0];
    imageView.frame = // set frame here
    [self addSubView:imageView];
    self.roundedImageView = imageView;
}
```

Comment: The AsyncImageView is not in the table view cell. It's in the RoundedImageView, which is in the table view cell.

Comment: Ok, is the `AsyncImageView` outlet on the RoundedImageView also?

Comment: Yes, it is connected.

Comment: If you right-click the `RoundedImageView`object in the nib, can you see that the connection is made there? If you right-click File's Owner, can you verify that no connections are made?

Comment: Also, can you post the code for both the cell and `RoundedImageView`? It would help to determine if something else is going on.

Comment: When I right-click the RoundedImageView object in the cell nib, I see profilePicture   -   InviteFriendsCell - InviteFriendsCell in the referencing outlets section. And when I click File's Owner in the cell there are no connections.  (profilePicture is the name of the IBOutlet property for the RoundedImageView)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46520/discussion-between-user2973562-and-austin)

Comment: Ok, so that means your `AsyncImageView` is not actually connected to the `RoundedImageView`; it's just a subview. Right click and drag from the `RoundedImageView` to the `AsyncImageView` to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are creating an instance of the view, probably with:

```
RoundedImageView *v = [[RoundedImageView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
```

this doesn't use the NIB file. You need to load the NIB with:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:... bundle:nil];
NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:... options:nil];
```

Then you can get the instance of `RoundedImageView` as:

```
RoundedImageView *v = views[0];
```